# Add a column that iterates/ counts every time a sequence resets

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have a dataframe, with a column that increases with every row, and periodically (though not regularly) resets back to 1.
I'd like to track/ count these resets in separate column. This for-loop example does exactly what I want, but is incredibly slow when applied to large datasets. Is there a better/ quicker/ more R way to do this same operation:

```
ColA<-seq(1,20)
ColB<-rep(seq(1,5),4)

DF<-data.frame(ColA, ColB)
DF$ColC<-NA

DF[1,'ColC']<-1

#Removing line 15 and changing line 5 to 1.1 per comments in answer
DF<-DF[-15,]
DF[5,2]<-0.1

for(i in seq(1,nrow(DF)-1)){
  
  print(i)
  
  MyRow<-DF[i+1,]
  
  if(MyRow$ColB < DF[i,'ColB']){
    DF[i+1,"ColC"]<-DF[i,"ColC"] +1
  }else{
    DF[i+1,"ColC"]<-DF[i,"ColC"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try `data.table::fifelse` or `dplyr::if_else` which are faster.

Comment: It is useally not helpfull to print objects inside for loops, this `print(i)` part could be deleted altogether

Comment: I usually print within a for loop to keep track of progress and make notes of anything of interest. Is there an issue with printing from a for loop?

Comment: It is not a problem at all. I just feel that, in longer scripts, this pollutes the console, and may confuse us beause the printed intermediate objects can be mistakenly considered as outputs from function call. But it should not bring any problems for you if you are thoughtful about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a loop here. We can just use the vectorized `cumsum`. This ought to be faster:

```
DF$ColC<-cumsum(DF$ColB==1)

DF
```

To keep using varying variable reset values that are always lower then the previous value, use `cumsum(ColB < lag(ColB))`:

```
DF %>% mutate(ColC = cumsum(ColB < lag(ColB, default = Inf)))

   ColA ColB ColC
1     1  1.0    1
2     2  2.0    1
3     3  3.0    1
4     4  4.0    1
5     5  0.1    2
6     6  1.0    2
7     7  2.0    2
8     8  3.0    2
9     9  4.0    2
10   10  5.0    2
11   11  1.0    3
12   12  2.0    3
13   13  3.0    3
14   14  4.0    3
16   16  1.0    4
17   17  2.0    4
18   18  3.0    4
19   19  4.0    4
20   20  5.0    4
```

Comment: Thanks- this does replicate my desired results. But I was hoping to keep with a system that works using "<" logic. This answer works when the reset goes back to 1, but would fail if the reset value was 1.1, or 2.
For example, if I added a line DF[5,2]<-1.1, this answer does not pick up on the reset

Comment: Please show a proper reproducible example then. I did not understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks- I've edited the above question as per my above comments

Comment: Ok please se the updated answer, tell me if it is Ok now